# Creating a 3 column layout of checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to arrange a list of checkboxes into 3 columns such as:

```
A    F    L
B    G    M
C    H    N
D    I    O
E    K    ...
```

Currently I have code which does this, but if the number of checkboxes isn't divisible by 3 then it goes out of range and throws a null reference exception. The number of checkboxes that I have can vary so I can't hardcoe it to  a number which is divisible by 3.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
@{
    var rows = (Model.BettingOffices.Count()) % 10 == 0
        ? (Model.BettingOffices.Count) / 10
        : ((Model.BettingOffices.Count) / 10) + 1;
}

<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="400">
                @Model.BettingOffices.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault().OfficeName
                <input name="selectedShops" type="checkbox" 
                    value="@Model.BettingOffices[i].OfficeName"/>
            </td>
            <td width="400">
                @Model.BettingOffices.Skip(i + rows).FirstOrDefault().OfficeName
                <input name="selectedShops" type="checkbox" 
                    value="@Model.BettingOffices[i + rows].OfficeName" />
            </td>
            <td width="400">
                @Model.BettingOffices.Skip(i + rows * 2).FirstOrDefault().OfficeName
                <input name="selectedShops" type="checkbox" 
                    value="@Model.BettingOffices[i + rows * 2].OfficeName" />
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Is there any way I can stop it from going out of range and throwing the exception?

Comment: What do you want to happen if it isn't divisible by 3?  You modulo 3 to determine how many sets of 3 are available though within your total count and then +1 or -1 to the rows based on how you want to handle the remainder.

Comment: Check before insert every td that length of the betting office is greater then then i , i + row , i + row*2

Comment: You can also try out the `column-count` css property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

Comment: It'll be easier if you make your markup insert only one `<td>` per loop rather than 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just utilize CSS and stop using HTML for layout style.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 3</label></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkboxes ul, .checkboxes li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.checkboxes li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:33.3333%;
}
```

You might need to tweak the display a little, but that will get you mostly there. The list items will fill as much of the line as possible and then automatically wrap to the next line, so based on a width of 33.3333% you'll get 3 per line.

Or, even better go fully responsive by utilizing some CSS library with grids (you can roll your own, but why?) For example, with Bootstrap, you could do:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled row">
    <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 1</label></li>
    <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 2</label></li>
    <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-6"><label><input type="checkbox"/> CheckBox 3</label></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

No additional CSS is required and you get the bonus of being able to change how many appear on a line responsively. For example, in the code above, medium-sized and up displays get three per line (Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid, so one-third of that is 4), while a very small display like a phone in portrait will get only 2 (12/2 = 6). This is *much* more flexible than using HTML, especially with tables which will absolutely bork the display on a small device.